# How can I calculate the coupling coefficient between two coils?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electromagnetic, coupling, wireless-charging

I have two planar, circular coils of different number of turns, inductances, and radius, stacked on top of each other. How can I calculate their coupling coefficient (k) based on their properties and the distance between them? (suppose they will still be parallel the whole time and they won't tilt)

Comment: Accurately? With great difficulty. Even single turn coils are mathematically problematic.

Comment: certain very symmetric geometries have exact solutions, for others you will have to flog through nasty Biot-Savart integrals yourself, unless you make some simplifying approximations to get an estimate